# How to pass message to 404 page without using querystring?

Tags: http-status-code-404, message

How to pass message to 404 page without using querystring?

Comment: What language? Which tech? Please more spesific !

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use JavaScript, then here goes:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "..."; // your 404 page goes here.
```

Hope it helps :)